# What to do when react give error of 'Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Component`). '

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

React gives me an error of 'Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Component`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `NAvBar`, follow the stack trace as described in [https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render'](https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render%27), While Reandering 'App' component.

To solve this kind of error while rendering you need to use 'useState' hook for rendering data in that particular 'component'. By using useState the app only renders when the hook data is changed. This may solve the error

Comment: can you elaborate more? how does your code look like?
are passing the setState from a parent compoent to a child component and the using it directly  in the body of the child compoenent?

Comment: please provide a [mre]. also the link is broken and looks like the question could use some formatting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.